# ui-sref with multiple url paramas

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

How can I generate the following link with ui-router:

```
.state('main.mystate', {
  url: '/foo/:val1/bar/:val2',
  templateUrl: 'app/components/space/spaceDetails.tpl.html',
  controller: 'SpaceDetailsCtrl'
})
```

This is not working:

```
<a ui-sref=".mystate({foo : '{{val1}}', bar : '{{val2}}'}">{{name}}</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

In state you defined, you have only 2 variables, *val1* and *val2*, so you must pass an object to `ui-sref`with that keys

```
<a ui-sref="main.mystate({val1: 123, val2: 456})">{{name}}</a>
```

Now in `SpaceDetailsCtrl` you can access *val1* by `$stateParams.val1`
Notice that I removed *foo* variable from `ui-sref`, because it's not used.